# Cannot create a new configuration database with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to create a new SharePoint 2010 farm using PowerShell. I use the following command:

```
New-SPConfigurationDatabase
```

When issuing this command (and providing the needed parameters) I get the following error:

```
New-SPConfigurationDatabase : This SharePoint farm currently has pending upgrades.
The cmdlet New-SPConfigurationDatabase cannot be executed until the upgrade is completed.
```

When running the "SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard" I'm able to create a farm.

I have a freshly installed Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL 2008 R2 on the same box (it's a demo box) and the SharePoint 2010 binaries installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

**`psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait –force`**

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I thought it wouldn't help to run this as I did not have a farm present yet.